# Question about laptop trackpad

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, laptop

I'm a bit of a newbie on here and transferred from Windows to Ubuntu on a fresh install and is currently my main OS on this laptop. The trackpad on my laptop will work fine for about the first two minutes and then gets a considerable amount of lag and stutter. I know that it's the trackpad because I've tried two separate external mice and the both work fine. I installed synaptic because I heard that that helped some people with trackpad recognition but no dice. The drivers are on there because I see a driver for the trackpad when I pull up a list of drivers in the terminal. I'm using the most current version of long running Ubuntu (16.04).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying libinput- there is even a source out there to add gesture support. What laptop model are you using? It is probably a common issue.

Comment: Acer Aspire E5-575G-53VG Laptop with i5 and 256 gb SSD

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Went into the BIOS and changed the track pad settings from "Advanced" to "Basic" and then saved the changes and it works fine now